# Why is server share selectively non-writeable?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, network-share, permissions

A Win2008R2 server `ServS` which serves a network share `tools` with share permissions `Everyone/Read` and `appuser/Modify`.

On another Win2008R2 server `ServApp`, I open an rdp session with `myaccount`. I open a cmd, execute `net use \\ServS\tools * /u:DOMAIN\appuser`, then issue `md \\ServS\tools\app\can-i-write`.
It works fine and folder is created.

On ServApp, I now open an rdp session with `appuser`. I open a cmd and issue `md \\ServS\tools\app\can-i-write`. I got an **access is denied** error.

In the same session, I open an **elevated** cmd and issue again `md \\ServS\tools\app\can-i-write`. I also got an **access is denied** error.

**Edit**:
In the same session, in a cmd, I **map** the `\\ServS\tools` with the same credentials as the current session (DOMAIN\appuser). `md y:\app\can-i-write` works fine. I can create the folder. I still cannot through an explorer in the same session.

- All the servers and the 2 accounts are in the same DOMAIN.
- NTFS permissions are OK (Modify on the `app` branch). Confirmed through successful writes.

I don’t understand the logic, nor the way we are blocked when directly connected.

Any help to understand and fix that is welcomed.

Comment: Check NTFS permissions as well. Remember most restrictive applies.

Comment: NTFS permissions are OK (Modify on all the ...\app branch). One proof is that it works when explicitly mapped.